# How to make my search bar stay still while adding new blocks

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi and thanks for the great job.

Okay my question is a little bit complicated ...I have a nicely designed header with a search bar.

I want to add a block at the left of the search bar , but one thing happened : my search bar move to the right and therefore no more aligned with my header top nav links :

Pic 1 : Before I add the logo block , top links and search bar are vertically aligned.
[image]

and When I add a block that is supposed to contains my logo , the search bar moves to the right and the alignment is broken ...

Pic2 : after I add the logo block , the search bar moves to the right , and the alignment is broken.

[image]

This is the URL of my project : http://69.64.88.50/ where you access access the source code.

My question is quite simple : I would like the yellow block to not make the search bar moving to the right and keep the alignment. What should I do ?!?!

I know my question is tricky but I would greatly appreciate any help or clue about how I might solve it from our community.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

**CSS**

```css
.header-middle-container {
    position: relative;
}
.header-logo-block {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

**Javascript**

```js
$('.header-logo-block').css('width', ($(window).width() - $('.container').width()) / 2 );
```

Comment: Welcome @Gabriel D.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely position the logo.

```css
.header-middle-container {
    position: relative;
}
.header-logo-block {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML><htmllang="en-us"> 
<base href="http://69.64.88.50/">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta name="robots" content="index,follow"/>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0"/>
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
   <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="/img/favicon.ico?1487631146"/>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon.ico?1487631146"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat%7COrbitron:900%7CPT+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,cyrillic" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/global.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/autoload/highdpi.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/autoload/jquery.bxslider.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/autoload/responsive-tables.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/autoload/uniform.default.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/product_list.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/modules/blocktags/blocktags.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/modules/homefeatured/homefeatured.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/modules/smartblog/css/smartblogstyle.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/modules/smartblogtag/css/smartblogtags.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/modules/tmheaderaccount/views/css/front.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/modules/tmproductvideos/views/css/video/video-js.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/modules/tmproductvideos/views/css/tmproductvideos.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/modules/tmsearch/views/css/tmsearch.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/jquery/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/modules/tmmegalayout/views/css/tmmegalayout.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/modules/tmmediaparallax/views/css/tmmediaparallax.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/modules/tmmediaparallax/views/css/rd-parallax.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/modules/tmhtmlcontent/css/hooks.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/theme1384/css/modules/favoriteproducts/favoriteproducts.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" media="all"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/modules/easyauth/views/css/sign.css" media="all"/>
   <script type="text/javascript">
var FancyboxI18nClose = 'Close';
var FancyboxI18nNext = 'Next';
var FancyboxI18nPrev = 'Previous';
var ajaxsearch = true;
var baseDir = 'http://69.64.88.50/';
var baseUri = 'http://69.64.88.50/index.php';
var contentOnly = false;
var currency = {"id":1,"name":"Dollar","iso_code":"USD","iso_code_num":"840","sign":"$","blank":"0","conversion_rate":"1.000000","deleted":"0","format":"1","decimals":"1","active":"1","prefix":"$ ","suffix":"","id_shop_list":null,"force_id":false};
var currencyBlank = 0;
var currencyFormat = 1;
var currencyRate = 1;
var currencySign = '$';
var displayList = true;
var favorite_products_url_add = 'http://69.64.88.50/index.php?process=add&fc=module&module=favoriteproducts&controller=actions';
var favorite_products_url_remove = 'http://69.64.88.50/index.php?process=remove&fc=module&module=favoriteproducts&controller=actions';
var highDPI = true;
var id_lang = 1;
var instantsearch = false;
var isGuest = 0;
var isLogged = 0;
var isMobile = false;
var page_name = 'index';
var priceDisplayMethod = 1;
var priceDisplayPrecision = 0;
var quickView = false;
var roundMode = 2;
var search_url_local = 'http://69.64.88.50/index.php?fc=module&module=tmsearch&controller=search';
var static_token = '2c7173b441c5cb594483cf8a9c7d4933';
var tmsearch_description = true;
var tmsearch_height = 800;
var tmsearch_image = true;
var tmsearch_limit = true;
var tmsearch_limit_num = 6;
var tmsearch_manufacturer = true;
var tmsearch_price = true;
var tmsearch_reference = true;
var tmsearch_scroll = true;
var token = '7bcc6800d6784049fb2a85adbf82231e';
var usingSecureMode = false;
</script>
<script src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script><script src="/js/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script><script src="/js/jquery/plugins/jquery.easing.js"></script><script src="/js/tools.js"></script><script src="/themes/theme1384/js/global.js"></script><script src="/themes/theme1384/js/autoload/10-bootstrap.min.js"></script><script src="/themes/theme1384/js/autoload/14-device.min.js"></script><script src="/themes/theme1384/js/autoload/15-jquery.total-storage.min.js"></script><script src="/themes/theme1384/js/autoload/15-jquery.uniform-modified.js"></script><script src="/themes/theme1384/js/autoload/16-jquery.scrollmagic.min.js"></script><script src="/themes/theme1384/js/autoload/17-jquery.scrollmagic.debug.js"></script><script src="/themes/theme1384/js/autoload/18-TimelineMax.min.js"></script><script src="/themes/theme1384/js/autoload/19-TweenMax.min.js"></script><script src="/themes/theme1384/js/autoload/20-jquery.bxslider.js"></script><script src="/themes/theme1384/js/products-comparison.js"></script><script src="/js/validate.js"></script><script src="/modules/tmheaderaccount/views/js/front.js"></script><script src="/modules/tmproductvideos/views/js/video/video.js"></script><script src="/js/jquery/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script><script src="/themes/theme1384/js/modules/tmsearch/views/js/tmsearch.js"></script><script src="/themes/theme1384/js/modules/tmmegalayout/views/js/tmmegalayout.js"></script><script src="/modules/tmmediaparallax/views/js/jquery.rd-parallax.min.js"></script><script src="/modules/tmmediaparallax/views/js/jquery.youtubebackground.js"></script><script src="/modules/tmmediaparallax/views/js/jquery.vide.min.js"></script><script src="/modules/tmmediaparallax/views/js/tmmediaparallax.js"></script><script src="/modules/favoriteproducts/favoriteproducts.js"></script><script src="/js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script><script src="/modules/easyauth/views/js/sign.js"></script><script src="/modules/easyauth/views/js/sign-pop.js"></script><script src="/themes/theme1384/js/index.js"></script>        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var elem = $('#tmhtmlcontent_home .parallax_banner');
            if (elem.length) {
                $('body').append('        <div class=\"rd-parallax rd-parallax-1\">\n                                                                                                                            <div class=\"rd-parallax-layer\" data-offset=\"0\" data-speed=\"0.3\" data-type=\"media\" data-fade=\"false\" data-url=\"/img/cms/parallax.jpg\" data-direction=\"normal\"><\/div>\n                                                <div class=\"rd-parallax-layer\" data-offset=\"0\" data-speed=\"0\" data-type=\"html\" data-fade=\"false\" data-direction=\"normal\"><div class=\"parallax-main-layout\"><\/div><\/div>\n        <\/div>\n    ');
                var wrapper = $('.rd-parallax-1');
                elem.before(wrapper);
                $('.rd-parallax-1 .parallax-main-layout').replaceWith(elem);
                win = $(window);
                            }
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).on('load', function(){
                $.RDParallax();
                $('.rd-parallax-layer video').each(function(){
                    $(this)[0].play();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<bodyid="index"class="indexshow-left-columnhide-right-columnlang_entwo-columns"><div class="old-ie"> <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/.."> <img src="http://69.64.88.50/themes/theme1384/img/ie8-panel/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today."/> </a> </div>
<div id="page">
<div class="header-container">
   <header id="header">
            <div class="nav">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <nav><nav>
 <div class="header_info">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Get Help</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact Us</li></a>
   <li><a href="#">Suggestions</li></a>
   <li><a href="#">Product Database</li></a>
   <li><a href="#">Customer Service</li></a>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="header-login">
  <div class="current header_user_info"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Sign In</a></div>
  <ul id="header-login-content" class="toogle_content">
       <li>
     <form action="http://69.64.88.50/index.php?controller=authentication" method="post" id="header_login_form">
      <div id="create_header_account_error" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none;"></div>
      <div class="form_content clearfix">
       <div class="form-group">
        <input class="is_required validate account_input form-control" data-validate="isEmail" type="text" id="header-email" name="header-email" placeholder="Email address" value="" />
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <span><input class="is_required validate account_input form-control" type="password" data-validate="isPasswd" id="header-passwd" name="header-passwd" placeholder="Password" value="" autocomplete="off" /></span>
       </div>
       <p class="submit">
        <button type="button" id="HeaderSubmitLogin" name="HeaderSubmitLogin" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
         <i class="fa fa-lock left"></i> 
         Sign in
        </button>
       </p>
       <p>
        <a href="http://69.64.88.50/index.php?controller=my-account" class="create">Create an account</a>
       </p>
       <div class="clearfix">
        
       </div>
      </div>
     </form>
    </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
</nav>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
            <div class="header-middle-container">
   <div class="header-logo-block">
   logo_container_here
   </div> 
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div id="header_logo"></div>
               <div id="tmsearch" class="clearfix">
  <span class="btn-toogle active"></span>
   <form id="tmsearchbox" method="get" action="//69.64.88.50/index.php?controller=search">
  <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="search"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="position"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="orderway" value="desc"/>
  <input class="tm_search_query form-control" type="text" id="tm_search_query" name="search_query" placeholder="What are you shopping for today ?" value=""/>
  </form>
  <button class="submit-buttons" id="search-bar-button" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>
            </div>
 
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-nav">
         <nav> 
    <a href="#">Groceries</a>
    <a href="#">Household</a>
    <a href="#">Pet Supplies</a>
    <a href="#">School & Office</a>
   </nav>
      </div>
   </header>
</div>
<div class="columns-container">
<div id="columns" class="container">
<div id="slider_row">
   </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-left col-md-12col-lg-12">
<div class="row">
<div id="center_column" class="center_column col-xs-12 col-md-12col-lg-12">


  <div class="clearfix">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla dictum eros odio, id pellentesque ante vehicula quis. Duis non malesuada ante, at scelerisque augue. Mauris in blandit nulla, et pulvinar lorem. Pellentesque hendrerit enim dictum urna euismod feugiat. Nam volutpat et dui sit amet ullamcorper. Maecenas sit amet bibendum urna, vel facilisis tellus. Nam sed nulla augue. Mauris placerat mattis ullamcorper.

Sed non metus imperdiet, sollicitudin massa pretium, accumsan dui. In id magna ut ligula vehicula rhoncus. Phasellus fringilla vestibulum sapien nec placerat. Vestibulum tempus tempus ante, nec imperdiet ante hendrerit ut. Suspendisse vel risus vitae sem pellentesque sollicitudin sed vel augue. Aenean sagittis faucibus ex, sollicitudin consequat neque tempor id. Maecenas odio lorem, pulvinar condimentum gravida ac, scelerisque sit amet libero. Fusce nec libero sodales, venenatis orci in, cursus quam.

Donec porttitor eget nibh sit amet finibus. Donec vitae tortor nec erat ultrices finibus. Nulla sodales euismod risus at ullamcorper. Praesent pretium risus in dolor dictum convallis. Cras quis vehicula purus. Integer molestie interdum purus quis euismod. Sed sagittis eros eget nibh dapibus posuere.

Morbi mattis tellus eget luctus imperdiet. Praesent porttitor ornare ligula, quis maximus purus porta et. Sed id varius magna. Sed rhoncus aliquam hendrerit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam vestibulum luctus varius. Fusce vel congue urna. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ut lorem tellus. Fusce tincidunt tincidunt lorem vitae dictum. Maecenas vel felis erat. Mauris commodo lectus eget sapien vestibulum tincidunt. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Morbi sollicitudin ullamcorper nisl, eget iaculis justo ultrices non. Nunc blandit magna at laoreet elementum. Nulla feugiat massa in sollicitudin interdum. Vivamus et mauris suscipit, cursus nulla eu, euismod sapien. Donec rutrum erat massa, sed pellentesque mi vestibulum non. Pellentesque ut tellus sodales, hendrerit metus ultricies, vestibulum elit. Quisque interdum id ligula vitae accumsan. Mauris non tellus risus. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla dictum eros odio, id pellentesque ante vehicula quis. Duis non malesuada ante, at scelerisque augue. Mauris in blandit nulla, et pulvinar lorem. Pellentesque hendrerit enim dictum urna euismod feugiat. Nam volutpat et dui sit amet ullamcorper. Maecenas sit amet bibendum urna, vel facilisis tellus. Nam sed nulla augue. Mauris placerat mattis ullamcorper.

Sed non metus imperdiet, sollicitudin massa pretium, accumsan dui. In id magna ut ligula vehicula rhoncus. Phasellus fringilla vestibulum sapien nec placerat. Vestibulum tempus tempus ante, nec imperdiet ante hendrerit ut. Suspendisse vel risus vitae sem pellentesque sollicitudin sed vel augue. Aenean sagittis faucibus ex, sollicitudin consequat neque tempor id. Maecenas odio lorem, pulvinar condimentum gravida ac, scelerisque sit amet libero. Fusce nec libero sodales, venenatis orci in, cursus quam.

Donec porttitor eget nibh sit amet finibus. Donec vitae tortor nec erat ultrices finibus. Nulla sodales euismod risus at ullamcorper. Praesent pretium risus in dolor dictum convallis. Cras quis vehicula purus. Integer molestie interdum purus quis euismod. Sed sagittis eros eget nibh dapibus posuere.

Morbi mattis tellus eget luctus imperdiet. Praesent porttitor ornare ligula, quis maximus purus porta et. Sed id varius magna. Sed rhoncus aliquam hendrerit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam vestibulum luctus varius. Fusce vel congue urna. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ut lorem tellus. Fusce tincidunt tincidunt lorem vitae dictum. Maecenas vel felis erat. Mauris commodo lectus eget sapien vestibulum tincidunt. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Morbi sollicitudin ullamcorper nisl, eget iaculis justo ultrices non. Nunc blandit magna at laoreet elementum. Nulla feugiat massa in sollicitudin interdum. Vivamus et mauris suscipit, cursus nulla eu, euismod sapien. Donec rutrum erat massa, sed pellentesque mi vestibulum non. Pellentesque ut tellus sodales, hendrerit metus ultricies, vestibulum elit. Quisque interdum id ligula vitae accumsan. Mauris non tellus risus. 


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla dictum eros odio, id pellentesque ante vehicula quis. Duis non malesuada ante, at scelerisque augue. Mauris in blandit nulla, et pulvinar lorem. Pellentesque hendrerit enim dictum urna euismod feugiat. Nam volutpat et dui sit amet ullamcorper. Maecenas sit amet bibendum urna, vel facilisis tellus. Nam sed nulla augue. Mauris placerat mattis ullamcorper.

Sed non metus imperdiet, sollicitudin massa pretium, accumsan dui. In id magna ut ligula vehicula rhoncus. Phasellus fringilla vestibulum sapien nec placerat. Vestibulum tempus tempus ante, nec imperdiet ante hendrerit ut. Suspendisse vel risus vitae sem pellentesque sollicitudin sed vel augue. Aenean sagittis faucibus ex, sollicitudin consequat neque tempor id. Maecenas odio lorem, pulvinar condimentum gravida ac, scelerisque sit amet libero. Fusce nec libero sodales, venenatis orci in, cursus quam.

Donec porttitor eget nibh sit amet finibus. Donec vitae tortor nec erat ultrices finibus. Nulla sodales euismod risus at ullamcorper. Praesent pretium risus in dolor dictum convallis. Cras quis vehicula purus. Integer molestie interdum purus quis euismod. Sed sagittis eros eget nibh dapibus posuere.

Morbi mattis tellus eget luctus imperdiet. Praesent porttitor ornare ligula, quis maximus purus porta et. Sed id varius magna. Sed rhoncus aliquam hendrerit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam vestibulum luctus varius. Fusce vel congue urna. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ut lorem tellus. Fusce tincidunt tincidunt lorem vitae dictum. Maecenas vel felis erat. Mauris commodo lectus eget sapien vestibulum tincidunt. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Morbi sollicitudin ullamcorper nisl, eget iaculis justo ultrices non. Nunc blandit magna at laoreet elementum. Nulla feugiat massa in sollicitudin interdum. Vivamus et mauris suscipit, cursus nulla eu, euismod sapien. Donec rutrum erat massa, sed pellentesque mi vestibulum non. Pellentesque ut tellus sodales, hendrerit metus ultricies, vestibulum elit. Quisque interdum id ligula vitae accumsan. Mauris non tellus risus. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla dictum eros odio, id pellentesque ante vehicula quis. Duis non malesuada ante, at scelerisque augue. Mauris in blandit nulla, et pulvinar lorem. Pellentesque hendrerit enim dictum urna euismod feugiat. Nam volutpat et dui sit amet ullamcorper. Maecenas sit amet bibendum urna, vel facilisis tellus. Nam sed nulla augue. Mauris placerat mattis ullamcorper.

Sed non metus imperdiet, sollicitudin massa pretium, accumsan dui. In id magna ut ligula vehicula rhoncus. Phasellus fringilla vestibulum sapien nec placerat. Vestibulum tempus tempus ante, nec imperdiet ante hendrerit ut. Suspendisse vel risus vitae sem pellentesque sollicitudin sed vel augue. Aenean sagittis faucibus ex, sollicitudin consequat neque tempor id. Maecenas odio lorem, pulvinar condimentum gravida ac, scelerisque sit amet libero. Fusce nec libero sodales, venenatis orci in, cursus quam.

Donec porttitor eget nibh sit amet finibus. Donec vitae tortor nec erat ultrices finibus. Nulla sodales euismod risus at ullamcorper. Praesent pretium risus in dolor dictum convallis. Cras quis vehicula purus. Integer molestie interdum purus quis euismod. Sed sagittis eros eget nibh dapibus posuere.

Morbi mattis tellus eget luctus imperdiet. Praesent porttitor ornare ligula, quis maximus purus porta et. Sed id varius magna. Sed rhoncus aliquam hendrerit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam vestibulum luctus varius. Fusce vel congue urna. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ut lorem tellus. Fusce tincidunt tincidunt lorem vitae dictum. Maecenas vel felis erat. Mauris commodo lectus eget sapien vestibulum tincidunt. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Morbi sollicitudin ullamcorper nisl, eget iaculis justo ultrices non. Nunc blandit magna at laoreet elementum. Nulla feugiat massa in sollicitudin interdum. Vivamus et mauris suscipit, cursus nulla eu, euismod sapien. Donec rutrum erat massa, sed pellentesque mi vestibulum non. Pellentesque ut tellus sodales, hendrerit metus ultricies, vestibulum elit. Quisque interdum id ligula vitae accumsan. Mauris non tellus risus. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla dictum eros odio, id pellentesque ante vehicula quis. Duis non malesuada ante, at scelerisque augue. Mauris in blandit nulla, et pulvinar lorem. Pellentesque hendrerit enim dictum urna euismod feugiat. Nam volutpat et dui sit amet ullamcorper. Maecenas sit amet bibendum urna, vel facilisis tellus. Nam sed nulla augue. Mauris placerat mattis ullamcorper.

Sed non metus imperdiet, sollicitudin massa pretium, accumsan dui. In id magna ut ligula vehicula rhoncus. Phasellus fringilla vestibulum sapien nec placerat. Vestibulum tempus tempus ante, nec imperdiet ante hendrerit ut. Suspendisse vel risus vitae sem pellentesque sollicitudin sed vel augue. Aenean sagittis faucibus ex, sollicitudin consequat neque tempor id. Maecenas odio lorem, pulvinar condimentum gravida ac, scelerisque sit amet libero. Fusce nec libero sodales, venenatis orci in, cursus quam.

Donec porttitor eget nibh sit amet finibus. Donec vitae tortor nec erat ultrices finibus. Nulla sodales euismod risus at ullamcorper. Praesent pretium risus in dolor dictum convallis. Cras quis vehicula purus. Integer molestie interdum purus quis euismod. Sed sagittis eros eget nibh dapibus posuere.

Morbi mattis tellus eget luctus imperdiet. Praesent porttitor ornare ligula, quis maximus purus porta et. Sed id varius magna. Sed rhoncus aliquam hendrerit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam vestibulum luctus varius. Fusce vel congue urna. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ut lorem tellus. Fusce tincidunt tincidunt lorem vitae dictum. Maecenas vel felis erat. Mauris commodo lectus eget sapien vestibulum tincidunt. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Morbi sollicitudin ullamcorper nisl, eget iaculis justo ultrices non. Nunc blandit magna at laoreet elementum. Nulla feugiat massa in sollicitudin interdum. Vivamus et mauris suscipit, cursus nulla eu, euismod sapien. Donec rutrum erat massa, sed pellentesque mi vestibulum non. Pellentesque ut tellus sodales, hendrerit metus ultricies, vestibulum elit. Quisque interdum id ligula vitae accumsan. Mauris non tellus risus. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla dictum eros odio, id pellentesque ante vehicula quis. Duis non malesuada ante, at scelerisque augue. Mauris in blandit nulla, et pulvinar lorem. Pellentesque hendrerit enim dictum urna euismod feugiat. Nam volutpat et dui sit amet ullamcorper. Maecenas sit amet bibendum urna, vel facilisis tellus. Nam sed nulla augue. Mauris placerat mattis ullamcorper.

Sed non metus imperdiet, sollicitudin massa pretium, accumsan dui. In id magna ut ligula vehicula rhoncus. Phasellus fringilla vestibulum sapien nec placerat. Vestibulum tempus tempus ante, nec imperdiet ante hendrerit ut. Suspendisse vel risus vitae sem pellentesque sollicitudin sed vel augue. Aenean sagittis faucibus ex, sollicitudin consequat neque tempor id. Maecenas odio lorem, pulvinar condimentum gravida ac, scelerisque sit amet libero. Fusce nec libero sodales, venenatis orci in, cursus quam.

Donec porttitor eget nibh sit amet finibus. Donec vitae tortor nec erat ultrices finibus. Nulla sodales euismod risus at ullamcorper. Praesent pretium risus in dolor dictum convallis. Cras quis vehicula purus. Integer molestie interdum purus quis euismod. Sed sagittis eros eget nibh dapibus posuere.

Morbi mattis tellus eget luctus imperdiet. Praesent porttitor ornare ligula, quis maximus purus porta et. Sed id varius magna. Sed rhoncus aliquam hendrerit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam vestibulum luctus varius. Fusce vel congue urna. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ut lorem tellus. Fusce tincidunt tincidunt lorem vitae dictum. Maecenas vel felis erat. Mauris commodo lectus eget sapien vestibulum tincidunt. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Morbi sollicitudin ullamcorper nisl, eget iaculis justo ultrices non. Nunc blandit magna at laoreet elementum. Nulla feugiat massa in sollicitudin interdum. Vivamus et mauris suscipit, cursus nulla eu, euismod sapien. Donec rutrum erat massa, sed pellentesque mi vestibulum non. Pellentesque ut tellus sodales, hendrerit metus ultricies, vestibulum elit. Quisque interdum id ligula vitae accumsan. Mauris non tellus risus. </div></div></div>
</div></div>
</div>
</div><div class="footer-container container">
    <div class="footer-container-contents">
        <div class="footer-copyright-mark"><a class="_blank" href="http://homecery.org"> Copyright&copy; 2017 Homecery, LLC . All rights reserved.</a></div><ul class="footer-links"><li><a href="#">User Agreement</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cookies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: OMgodness @micheal coker many many thanks !! You have been solving so many of my front-end problems !! I like you lol

Comment: @GabrielD. hah you're welcome. yes! I am looking for a new job ;) that's why I'm on here. I love it but I'm bored.

Comment: Please Email me @ gdiop@homecery.com

Comment: @GabrielD. oh I thought you were joking!

Comment: nope. I am very serious. Please email me for details ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can create that using css with relative and absolute positions.

Add "position: relative" value to your .header-middle-container css property and also add "position: absolute" to .header-logo-block with top and left "0" value, and also use bottom "0" if you want it to stretch.

It should look like this:

```
.header-middle-container {
    position: relative
}

.header-logo-block {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

That way your logo won't affect the position of search bar, however be careful with absolute positions and responsiveness.

Comment: Worked for me ! Thanks a lot !